# How can I upload data to Cache database?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have some xls/csv tables with several columns and over thousand of rows. I have created a class hierarchy, representing my subject, at Cache Studio. And now want to load data from my tables to this database. One class can contain data from different tables, and one table can provide data to different classes. So I need some flexible tool.

Answer (score 1):

In Caché we don't have such flexible tool, not sure that you can do it in other databases. If such tool exist, and it support working by ODBC/JDBC, you could also do it with Caché.

Any way the most correct way to do it, in your situation, is to write parser on COS by yourself. And it would be easy if it will be a CSV files only, for xls, you should made an access to Excel for reading it.